# How do I resolve an issue where two DHCP servers in the same network give the same IP address, say 192.168.2.4, to two different devices?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Considering the question above if I have computer ... whose IP address is obtained by one of these two DHCP servers, and I try to log in to 192.168.2.4; which device will I log on to?

Comment: Fix the configuration as suggested by Rikon.

Comment: How about NOT having two dhcp servers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two DHCPd servers should have different ranges, ie:

```
DHCP A: 192.168.2.1  - 50
DHCP B: 192.168.2.51 - 99
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The host that you log in to (I'm assuming you mean "connect to") isn't dependent on the server that you got your DHCP assigned IP address from (unless the server you're connecting to is on another network, in which case the router information that you got from DHCP will determine how your traffic is routed to the destination host).

It's dependent on which server answers the ARP query for the IP address that you're connecting to.

Comment: Also, many OSes will pickup the duplicate IP and stop using it...